# Android app to alarm based on sunrise/sunset time for a fixed location

Tags: android, alarm-clock

There is Samsung Bixby Routine on my device with Android 12 that alarms based on location but for it to work device location should always be on. While most of the time I keep it off.

I'm looking for an app that allows me to choose a city or input a coordinate for its sunset/sunrise time calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You can build anything like that yourself using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (not free, but with a lot of other utilities) and [MeteoTask](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.balda.meteotask):

- in MeteoTask you can set a predefined city location
- in Tasker you can use **Day/Night** (Plugin -> MeteoTask) state checking for day, then in the entry task use **Set Alarm** (System) action or directly play sound and vibrate with actions like **Music Play** (Media) and **Vibrate** (Alert)